# Silverlight with Isolated Storage - Port from Windows Forms with SQLite

Tags: silverlight, sqlite, com, isolatedstorage

I am about to port a Windows Form app to WPF or Silverlight. The current application uses a cache to store SQL responses temporaily as well as for later use in order not to have to run the queries again. The local cache should be able to handle 1 to 4 GB.

1) Is the Internal Storage capable to handle this amount of data? A search has not given me a clear answer so far, many talk about a 1MB limit, some say storage is of size long.

2) SQLite has C# managed code port, but I am not sure if that is stable enough to use in a professional application. Any experience or opinion?

3) Is it possible to use the SQLite ADO.Net provider for the Isolated storage or would it be an idea to run a local server that is responsible for the cache only? Or any way to achieve this through the COM access?

4) Any file based db system that you can recommend as a substitute for SQLite in case nothing else does work?

Any other ideas welcome, I need the local cache. If not, I need to do the application in Silverlight AND WPF and I would like to avoid that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 1 question:

> Is the Internal Storage capable to handle this amount of data? A
>   search has not given me a clear answer so far, many talk about a 1MB
>   limit, some say storage is of size long.

Basically, by default Silverlight apps are granted 1 Mb of storage but they can request an increase in its storage quota (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/17/tip-of-the-day-20-how-to-increase-the-isolated-storage-quota-for-your-app.aspx) for more details).

Hope this helps